# Getting jar not in the pom.xml

Tags: maven, objectify

I am confused why my web application is getting a Jar in its `Maven Dependencie`s even if I think its not on the pom.xml file.

Here's my complete [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/YteJVe0D) which the applications gets `objectify-2.2.3.jar`

However I need to put a new version of this jar and I am not sure why my application gets this jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do just a

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

on the console and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this jar is referenced by one of your direct dependencies.

Some IDEs can show the full dependency tree. I know this could be done with IntelliJ IDEAs maven view. I think Eclipse has a similar view.

There is also a [maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) for this.